# How to add padding/margin to images so that text is not abutting them?

Tags: html, github, markdown

I'm creating a personal website using Github. In this markdown file, I'm trying to align a photo to the left then have a brief intro of myself right next to the photo. This is my current code.

```
<img align="left" width="300" height="440" src="image/photo.JPG">
my introduction text goes here
```

What do I need to do to add some margin to the image so that the text is not bumping into the image? Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: the `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for a decade or more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```html
<img style="margin-right: 1.5rem" align="left" height="auto" width="300" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/introduction-concept-word-cork-board-77226561.jpg" />
<p>Hi, this is the introduction...</p>
```

Or you can opt to use a multi-column layout and specify a column gap to your liking:

```
<section id="introWrapper" style="column-count: 2; column-gap: 50px">
    <img>
    <p></p>
<section>
```